# fuel with the narrowest boiling temperature?

Tags: hydrocarbons, fuel

What commercially available fuel, such as kerosene or diesel, has the least variation in different hydrocarbon chains and thus the most uniform boiling point? I ask this because I'm searching for a fuel to use in a rocket engine, but unrefined fuels such as regular petroleum, which have a lot of variation in its constituents, will start to coke the engine plumbing when exposed to high temperatures. I understand that most commercially available fuels will do this, but are there any fuels which at the very least minimize this.

Comment: If I understand your question, you are looking for a pure hydrocarbon. Pure substances can be characterized by your requirements : 1) most uniform boiling point, and 2) least variation in hydrocarbon chain. So any pure hydrocarbon will meet your requirement.

Comment: Doesn't even have to be a hydrocarbon. Just any pure liquid that's got high energy content. Hydrazine is a classic one. There is. however, a specific grade of refined kerosene called RP-1 that has a narrower bp and is intended for rockets, though the bp range is still not what you'd get with a pure compound.

Comment: Compulsory reference to Ignition: an informal history of liquid rocket propellants by John D Clark. [On Amazon here](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Ignition-Informal-Propellants-University-Classics/dp/0813595835/ref=sr_1_1?crid=5TO9NVBN37V5&dchild=1&keywords=ignition+an+informal+history+of+liquid+rocket+propellants&qid=1599052011&s=books&sprefix=ignition%2Cinstant-video%2C163&sr=1-1). he specifically talks about special grades of kerosine with these properties.